# _ModerationStatus on list items is always draft from SPQuery

Tags: list-view, splist, spquery, draft

I am querying for list items in a timer job. 
The list has moderation enabled. It has various list items that have different approval status (e.g. scheduled, approved etc.).

However the query always returns all items in "draft" mode and there is no way of querying for items with different approval status. The same happens when I log in to the site as System Account and view the library, it will show all items in draft status.

Why is the moderation status not visible for the system account? Other moderation info such as comments are showing.

Edit:

Impersonating the Site Owner account works fine and the query returns all moderationinformation. 
E.g.

```
SPUserToken token = site.Owner.UserToken;
var impersonatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID, token);
```

Comment: Does it display differently for other accounts?

Comment: Yes it works correctly for other accounts.

Comment: I have this issue too and I found it will always show draft if the item has been "declared as record". If it is undeclared", it would show the correct approval status.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I believe you are right. I noticed the same thing much later.

Answer (score 0):

As tony wu pointed out, seems this has to do with the items being locked as records.
In our case, we were using in-place record management, which seems to affect the moderation status of item when viewing them as Sys admin or with an SPQuery.